# Cannot open Firefox in Windows Subsystem For Linux

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

- Firefox version: 77.0.1
- X Server: Vc X Server (VcXsrv)
- Ubuntu: 18.04 LTS

When I attempt to launch Firefox, I get the following message:

"Firefox has just been updated in the background. Click Restart Firefox to complete the update."

Doing so does not fix it.

What I have tried:

- Opening `about:config` and setting `browser.tabs.config.autostart` and `browser.tabs.config.autostart2` to `false`
- Opening `about:support` page and click on `Refresh Firefox` (this starts up firefox again, but the URL bar no longer works as well, so I cannot do about:config or about:support anymore)
- Updating and upgrading all packages with `apt`

Here are the first few errors I see when I attempt to start it up:

```
[Parent 11057, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-Wud6wF/firefox-77.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 19

Exiting due to channel error.   

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2000A0,name=PBrowser::Msg_SafeAreaInsetsChanged) Channel error: cannot send/recv

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x200096,name=PBrowser::Msg_LoadRemoteScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

There are many more after, but follow a similar format to those second two.

Am I just missing a package? Or is FF fundamentally just not compatible with WSL?

Comment: Are you running WSL1 or 2?  I had a ton of subtle issues with Chrome until switching to WSL2.

Comment: I'm on Windows 1909. Is that WSL1 or 2?

Comment: Run `wsl -l -v`.  If it has a version column you have 2 available.